# Converting ANTLR4 embedded java in python grammar to C#

Tags: java, c#, c#-4.0, antlr, antlr4

I am trying to implement the embedded java portion of the python3 grammar (https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/python3/Python3.g4)  to C#. There are a few attributes that I see being used in java that I am not able to find in the C# runtime implementation of ANTLR4.

Can someone please point me to what are the equivalent C# attributes for the following?

Line 100:

```
  private CommonToken commonToken(int type, String text) {
    int stop = this.getCharIndex() - 1;
    int start = text.isEmpty() ? stop : stop - text.length() + 1;
    return new CommonToken(this._tokenFactorySourcePair, type, DEFAULT_TOKEN_CHANNEL, start, stop);
  }
```

Here I am not able to find the `_tokenFactorySourcePair` attribute

Line 132:

```
  boolean atStartOfInput() {
    return super.getCharPositionInLine() == 0 && super.getLine() == 1;
  }
```

Here I am not able to find the `getCharPositionInLine()` attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Antlr4 assembly source from Github and added that to my project. Those attributes are present but are private. I just changed that and that fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `_tokenFactorySourcePair` has been made `protected` on Lexer in the current Antlr4 version so that should solve itself.

The property equivalent of `getCharPositionInLine()` is `Lexer.Column`